# How to follow paths of rings?

Tags: sonic-forces

There are multiple areas in the game (stage 7 - "Arsenal Pyramid" pictured) which imply that the character is able to boost along ring paths:

[image: screenshot]

There must be an ability similar to modern Sonic's homing attack?

Comment: Haven't played Sonic Forces, but starting WAY back in Sonic Adventure, Sonic has had an ability named Light Speed Dash to dash through lines of rings like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to play as Super Sonic selected as a character (note that **your score and best time won't be recorded**):

[image: character selection]

Super Sonic transformation occurs after collecting 50 rings. Press and hold "Wispon" button (see [manual](https://www.sonicthehedgehog.com/forces/manual/en/index.html?pid=5) > "unique character actions") to follow ring paths.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the Lightning wispon equipped. This allows you to perform the light dash on rings or enemies.